# How do defined methods work in Gradle?

Tags: methods, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

When I run my gradle task *test*, why are the tasks *local, dev, and uat* seem to be run as well? I am trying to only run *test*.

The actual output when I run *gradle test* is below (see pic). My desired output is below (see pic). What am I doing wrong in my code? I am new to Gradle/Groovy, so my apologies. thanks!

Code:
[image: Gradle Code of build.gradle file]

Actual Output:
[image: Command line output when running "gradle test"]

Desired Output:
[image: Output I wish I had]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use

```
someTask {
    someMethod()
}
```

then it means to gradle that it must call `someMethod()` when **configuring** the task, in the first phase that parses the build script and decides which tasks exist and what depends on what.

To define what must happen when the task is *executed*, in the second phase, you must use the following syntax:

```
someTask << {
    someMethod()
}
```

Comment: great, thank you! I knew I was missing something small.